# Looking for WordPress plugin to add role/group to a user and limit blog entries for this role/group

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am looking for an easy to use plugin which allows:

- Assign a "group" or "role" or "category" to a user (or several users)
- Assign this group/role/category to individual blog entries or blog categories
- Limit access (view only) to these blog entries for the users having this role/group/category.

The easiest way for the enduser creating the blog entries would be to assign a category for a blog entry and based on this category, only users "assigned" to this category would see the content.

Thanks
Andy

Comment: Sorry, but this question is off-topic here.  [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) specifically - `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.` Instead, please try to better describe your problem and what you have done so far to solve it.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to ask this questions at other places.

Comment: Just found it myself: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/groups/